# How to create a `files`-parameter for the bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add()-operator?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I'm trying to figure out how to do things with Python in Blender and am struggling really hard to get even the most basic things done. The construction of the `override`-parameter in my script below is probably not ideal but seems to work.

The `files`-arg is of course nonsense. As I understand it I would need to construct a `bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection` of `bpy.types.OperatorFileListElement`. But I have no clue how to initialize either of them.

```
import bpy

screen = bpy.context.window.screen

area   = [area for area in screen.areas if area.type == 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'][0]
region = [region for region in area.regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0]

override = {'window': bpy.context.window, 
            'screen': screen, 
            'area': area, 
            'region': region, 
            'scene': bpy.context.scene}

bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add(override, channel=3, files=("test",))
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the problem is just the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.ops.sequencer.html#bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add) (it's really misleading). Working code is:

```
bpy.ops.sequencer.image_strip_add(override, 
                                  channel=3,
                                  directory='/home/me/somewhere',
                                  files=({'name': "test"},))
```

The information what other keys the `dict` could have is possibly hidden somewhere in the docs. I haven't found it yet.

It seems to be a general concept in the Blender scripting api to "fish in collections". E.g. to create the `override` arg. But also if you want a reference to the object you just inserted you seem to need to fish in a collection. But maybe I just don't get it yet. (I hope so)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but for a start I would recommend using the up-to-date api documentation, here: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api

Comment: Don't use operators for this. See my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use operators to do this; they aren't intended to be called from Python.

The [regular data/function API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Sequences.html#bpy.types.Sequences.new_image) is much simpler to use:

```
import bpy

se = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor_create()
seq = se.sequences.new_image('hey', 'C:/temp/hey.png', 1, 1)
```